# Rate limit requests based on HTTP header value on nginx-ingress

Tags: kubernetes, rate-limiting, nginx-ingress

Is it possible to rate limit requests based on HTTP header value on nginx-ingress?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I didn't have kubernetes nginx ingress from nginxinc suggested solution here didn't work.

Manage to do it through configmap and annotation tweak.

**Configmap:**

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-configuration
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx-ingress
    chart: nginx-ingress-1.33.0-dev
    release: nginx-ingress
data:
  http-snippet: |
    limit_req_zone $http_authorization zone=my-zone:20m rate=5r/s;
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=my-zone:20m rate=10r/s;
    limit_req_zone $http_someheader zone=my-zone:20m rate=20r/s;
```

**Annotation in ingress resource:**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      limit_req zone=my-zone-1 burst=10 nodelay;
      limit_req_log_level notice;
      limit_req_status 429;
```

*Note: http-snippet is not allowed as annotation!*

**Example with different throtling for different locations defined by one ingress:**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location /content/images/ {
      limit_req zone=my-zone-2 burst=50 nodelay;
      }
      location /content/texts/ {
      limit_req zone=my-zone-3 burst=50 nodelay;
      }
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      limit_req zone=my-zone-1 burst=10 nodelay;
      limit_req_log_level notice;
      limit_req_status 429;
```

*Note that defining location here in **server-snippet** annotation doesn't allow you to define it further down in ingress*

Comment: So we would need to add a complete location definition in server-snippet?
How have you been able to mention the back-end in server snippet?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do it by creating ConfigMap file with the customized template containing 'limit_req_zone' directive, as shown on official NGINX Ingress examples of custom-annotations usage [here](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/46b807707b384fadc68d0c06d7d747a6e8f294f0/examples/custom-annotations/README.md#step-1---customize-the-template).

You should specify the key/variable to the limit_req_zone directive e.g.:

```
limit_req_zone $http_authorization_key ...
```

where $http_authorization_key variable corresponds to 'Authorization-Key' request header field*

*the last part of a variable name is the field name converted to lower case with dashes replaced by underscores (from official NGINX [doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_))

Comment: Is that possible only via annotations? Can't find reference in docs.